# Magento 2 - Base URL and Secure URL

Tags: magento2.3.4

Question reagarding magento 2.3.4 base url and base secure url.

Currently I have in both base and secure the same https url. Does this hurt in any way the performance and do I need to change base to http instead of https or should I leave it as is.

Best regards
Vincent

Answer (score 1):

If you want your store to be accessible with `http` protocol, then you should not put `https` in both URLs. Again, it's more about security than performance. If you've a valid security certificate then you can put `https` in both URLs and your store would only be accessible through `secure` protocol and vice versa. For example, if you've set both URLs with `https://localhost/magento2` then accessing it with `http://localhost/magento2` won't work. Hope you understand now!

Comment: Thanks Abdul, but the real question is does it hurt that I used the same https url for both secure and unsecure store url

Comment: If you're on local machine and testing then it doesn't matter but when your store is live then https is very much recommended since it is a secure protocol and by no mean it'd hurt anything, in fact it's a positive thing for your store's security. Quoting from magento official devdocs : "If your domain has a valid security certificate, you can configure the URLs of both the storefront and Admin to transmit data over a secure (https) channel. Without a valid security certificate, your store cannot operate with secure (SSL/TLS) protocol." Hope you get it now.

Comment: Hi Abdul, Not getting it. My question is does it hurt that at the field base url i used https instead of http see attached image https://imgur.com/a/fAn38hb

Comment: I've edited my answer.